# Add county borders to ggmap

Tags: ggmap

I did a map of five counties (comunas) of Chile by using ggmap and now I would like to add the borders and name of this counties to the map.

The first part i did it with this code:

```
# Mapa.
mapcrime <- ggmap(get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -70.75, lat = -33.195),
                                zoom = 11, scale = 1,
                                maptype ='roadmap',
                                color = 'bw'))+
    geom_point(data=original_data, aes(x=lat, y=lon, size=people, fill = sector), 
               color = "grey30", alpha=0.5, shape=21)+
    scale_size(name="Max labour", range=c(3,16), breaks=c(40, 80, 200, 400, 800, 1000), 
               labels = c("0 - 40", "41 - 80","81 - 200","201 - 400","401 - 1000","801 - 1000")) +
    labs(x = "",
         y = "") +
    labs(size = "Max labor", fill = "Sector")+
    theme_classic()+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(linewidth = 0.0, colour = "white"),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 13.0),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 11.0)
    )+
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("tomato", "gold","dodgerblue2","purple2","springgreen3"))+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 3.5)))
    

print(mapcrime)
```

However I do not know how to continue. The database that has the information of the counties's borders has the county code and the geometry (as multipolygon).